# graph request, retrieving dictionary value from parameter

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, fbsdk

I am new to iOS and programming in general for that matter, I believe this is a fairly basic question but I have sifted through page after page on google and can't find the answer.

How do I retrieve just the "first_name" value from the result of my Facebook graph request to Firebase. The result is stored as a dictionary and print(result) gives me the entire list of parameters. I just want to grab the "first_name" from the parameters dictionary. Thanks in advance!

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, 
first_name, email"]).start { (connection, result, err) in
        print(1234)

        if err != nil {
        print("failed to start graph request", err ?? "")
        return
        }
            print(result)

        let values: [String: AnyObject] = result as! [String : AnyObject]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if result is a Dictionary type you should be able to get the value like this `result["first_name"]`. You should definitely go over this doc https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html